# getting multiple radio buttons in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I'm here because I am new in rails and I really need help.

The thing is I have one model Answer that has one true or false attr, but I want to display on screen several questions at once on a form each one as a radio button, that I can do, the code is this:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: 'questionnaires', action: 'create') do %>
<% @questionnaire.questions.each do |question| %>
    <p><%= question.question_text %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(question.id, "true") %>
    <%= label_tag(:radio_yes, "yes") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(question.id, "false") %>
    <%= label_tag(:radio_no, "No") %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag 'Answer questionnaire' %>
```

The problem starts when I'm trying to retrieve this selects on the controller, how would i do to get the answer of each id? or there is some other way to display the radio buttons?

Comment: Take a look at `fields_for` to loop over each `question`.

Comment: I'm searching for it,but do you have an example?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Thanx man^^ helped a lot

Comment: If that will solve your issue, I can post is as an answer and you accept it

Comment: Just one last question, how do I iterate on the params now? i can get the first by using .first and stuf, but how ll i put on the array?

Comment: answer it Andrey, i ll accept^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Take a precise look at docs and you'll know, how to iterate over each question

Comment: but now i have something like this: on params
{"#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000040ce460>"=>"true", "#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000040c60a8>"=>"true", "#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000040c0c20>"=>"true", "#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000040b3070>"=>"true"}

how would I get each of then?

Comment: Got it^^ just iterate normally